# Conversion from C# to VB with ASP.Net-mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am trying to convert C# Razor Into VB Razor
Have Trouble with the following

When I Change

```
(Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

To

```
(Html.BeginForm(new With { .ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new With { .class = "checkbox" })
```

I Get Error

> "m not declare it may be inaccessible due to its protection level"

Also Kindly Explain This new C# Syntax

```
Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

and its equivalent in VB

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
```

should be

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
```

See: [How to: Create a Lambda Expression (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531298.aspx)

---

```
@Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

respectively

```
@Html.BeginForm(new With { .ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }
```

creates an anonymous type. See: [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
@Html.BeginForm(New With { _
    Key .ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl _
})
@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.RememberMe, New With { _
    Key .[class] = "checkbox" _
})
```

If you refer to `new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }` it's simply an [anonyimous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) type.